# Display ads on multiple Views by using single controller method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display different ads on multiple Views from single method. Currently, I have created separate controller method for the ads and then passing page name by using session from each View's controller method. I want to get rid off any code related to ads from each controller method.

Please suggest me way to do this.

Home controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ClsHomeContent model = new ClsHomeContent();
            List<Advertisement> advertList = new List<Advertisement>();    
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var advert = context.Advertisement.ToList();
            var pageName = context.Advertisement.Where(x => x.Page == "Home").Select(y => y.Page).FirstOrDefault();
            Session["PageName"] = pageName;

            return View(model);
        }
```

HorseTracker Controller

```
  public ActionResult HorseTracker()
    {

        List<Advertisement> advertList = new List<Advertisement>();
        var advert = context.Advertisement.ToList();
        var pageName = context.Advertisement.Where(x => x.Page == "HorseTracker").Select(y => y.Page).FirstOrDefault();
        Session["PageName"] = pageName;            
        return View(model);
    }
```

Then using this session value

```
 public ClsAdvertisment advertPosition()
        {
            List<Advertisement> advertList = new List<Advertisement>();
            ClsAdvertisment model = new ClsAdvertisment();
            var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            var advert = context.Advertisement.ToList();
            foreach (var advertisementData in advert)
            {
                if (advertisementData.Position == Session["PageName"] + "_Top_Left" || advertisementData.Position == Session["PageName"] + "_Top_Right" || advertisementData.Position == Session["PageName"] + "_Middle" || advertisementData.Position == Session["PageName"] + "_Left")
                {
                    advertList.Add(new Advertisement()
                    {
                        AdvertId = advertisementData.AdvertId,
                        Position = advertisementData.Position,
                        FilePath = advertisementData.FilePath,
                        Hemisphere = advertisementData.Hemisphere,
                        Link = advertisementData.Link,
                        Title = advertisementData.Title
                    });
                }
            }
            model.advertisement = advertList;
            return model;

        }

      [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult Advertisement()
        {
           var model= advertPosition();
            return PartialView("_pAdvertisement", model);
        }

     Created separate partial view

 foreach (var item in Model.advertisement)
                {
                    if (@item.Hemisphere == 1 && item.Position == (string)Session["PageName"]+"_Top_Left")
                    {
            <a href="@item.Link" title="@item.Title" target="_blank">
                @Html.Image(item.FilePath, "Image", "", "")
            </a>
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the parent controller and action methods in the child method using the `ParentActionViewContext` property of `ControllerContext`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Advertisement()
{
    ViewContext context = ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext;
    string controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    string actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
    ClsAdvertisment model = advertPosition(controllerName, actionName);
    return PartialView("_pAdvertisement", model);
}
```

Then modify your `advertPosition()` to

```
public ClsAdvertisment advertPosition(string controllerName, string actionName)
```

and within that method, select the ads to be displayed based on those values, and there is also no need to use `Session`.